# Twig render layout and include template not working

Tags: php, twig

This is my code, index.php

```
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    $template = $twig->load('index.html.twig');
    echo $template->renderBlock('content', ['pageTitle' => 'Hello world']);
```

in `templates/layouts/default.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'partials/header.html.twig' %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% include 'partials/footer.html.twig' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

In `templates/index.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'layouts/default.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>This is content</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

My directories:

```
templates/
      layouts/
            default.html.twig
      partials/
            header.html.twig
            footer.html.twig
      index.html.twig
```

It render only one text `'This is content'` and doesn't load `header.index.twig` and `footer.html.twig` content. Somebody can help me, thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: You mean `header.html.twig`?

Comment: Yes, i want include header and footer to layout